# How to read space and indentation in Java

Tags: java, indentation, space

I want to write a program that can read txt files and convert all of the indentations inside to spaces. So I need a way to read space and indentation in Java. Does anyone have any idea how to do it? Thanks a million!

Comment: Post what have you tried!!

Answer (score 0):

To find the tab character, simply look for '\t' in the text.

Answer (score 0):

to read space, equate your variable with `' '` which is holding your character from file.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this (even though not the most efficient) is to do something like this:

```
public String convertToSpaces(String input) {
    String res = input;
    res = res.replaceAll("\t", "    ");
    return res;
}
```

You can create a method that takes as a parameter your string, and replaces its whitespace characters with spaces.